# Automator Workflow doesn't show on Services menu in all apps

Tags: macos, google-chrome, applescript, automator

I created an automator workflow that opens a specific page in google chrome. When I assigned a keyboard shortcut to it, it only works when Chrome is the active application. How do I get this keyboard shortcut to work in any application not just chrome (have the workflow appear in Services for all applications)?

I tried giving access to automator in Security & Privacy > Privacy > Accessibility and restarting my mac after saving the automator workflow.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the reason why it wasn't working in other applications was because I had my workflow set to "Workflow receives `no input` in `GOOGLE CHROME`". When I changed this to `any application`, it works in all apps.[image]